# Android default color

Tags: android, colors, default

Is this possible to get default Android color (for example orange, when user pressed button)? I have list and I want to set default Android color to header.

Comment: What does you header of the List contains, you want to set the color in xml or dynamically in code?

Comment: its based on view define which you have to set in listview

Comment: Those orage colors you see on android are actually 9 patch images.

Comment: There is no difference: I can set color in xml or dynamically.

Comment: @blessenm: In my Samsung default colors are orange, but in HTC is green. I want adjust list color to system colors.

Comment: By default you list row should take the default list background of the phone unless you have specified a background yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are some default colors defined in `android.R.color`

```
Color c = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark);
```

I solved a similar problem by applying the default list item's appearance to my controls, which caused them to highlight when pressed in the same way as the native one.